Matplotlib not changing legend labels for a plot in python package pyAT
So I am attempting to use a python interface of Accelerator Toolbox (pyAT: link here) to simulate the path of a few particles through an energy spectrometer. From this interface, I've utilized a plotting function called plot_trajectory() (info here) to get the trajectory plot of my setup. My issue is that the default settings of the plotting function do not reflect the concepts that I want to show, and so I wanted to change the labels of the legend to reflect the paths of a low momentum particle, nominal momentum particle, and a high momentum particle. I tried a couple methods to change the labels, but keep getting an issue where the plot legend doesn't update to what I want to alter it to.
When I posted this question to the github for pyAT, I got an answer that seemed to work for someone else, but did not work for me. The script used was the following:
import at
import at.plot as atplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Lattice elements 
Dr1 = at.Drift('Dr', 0.5)
Bend1 = at.Dipole('Bend', 0.9666, 0.6789) 
Dr2 = at.Drift('Dr', 1)
Monitor1 = at.Monitor('Monitor')

# Lattice cell
ECS_cell_simple = at.Lattice([Dr1, Bend1, Dr2, Monitor1], name='ECS_Dipole_cell', energy=250E6) 

# Generate a set of particles with different momentum to track
x_01 = 0.001, 0.001, 0.001
xp_01 = 0.000 
y_01 = 0.001, 0.001, 0.001 
yp_01 = 0 
dp_01 = 0, -0.0001, 0.0001 
ct_01 = 0 

N=3
zeros = [0]*N

# Generate the distribution of particles 
r_in_list = np.array([x_01, zeros, zeros, zeros, dp_01, zeros])

#Plot particle trajectories
ECS_E_spectrometer = ECS_cell_simple.plot_trajectory(r_in_list.copy(), legend=True)

# Plot the trajectory function with alterations
[left,right,syn] = ECS_cell_simple.plot_trajectory(r_in_list.copy(), legend=True)

# Get the figure to be able to make changes
fig = left.get_figure()

# Change width of the function
fig.set_figwidth(11)

# Set axes ranges
left.set_ylim(0,2e-3)
#right.set_ylim(0,1) # There is not right y axis in this plot so right is None
#align.yaxes(left, 0, right, 0, 0.15)

# Set location of the legend
legend = left.get_legend()
legend.set_loc('upper left')

# Change legend names
legend.get_texts()[1].set_text('test')
legend.get_texts()[2].set_text('test')

# Change label name
#right.set_ylabel('$\\eta_x$')

From this script, the second plot for me stayed the same, but was changed according to the alterations outlined in the script for the other person helping me out. However, I do know I can alter plots with other simpler scripts, such as
plt.plot(range(10), label='Some very long label')
plt.plot(range(1,11), label='Short label')
L=plt.legend()
L.get_texts()[0].set_text('make it short')
L.get_texts()[1].set_text('longer')

which does change the legend labels. My question then comes down to why might this problem arise with pyAT specifically? I know this question might fall outside of the github, but any extra advice or recommendations would be greatly appreciated!
